# Theorem, cartesian product in open sets.

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus

How I can prove this property of open sets in $\mathbb R^{n}$?
If $A_{1}$ and $A_{2}$ are open sets, then $A_{1} \times A_{2}$ are a open set.
Thanks.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

The following makes use of the fact that the max metric and the Euclidean metric are equivalent.

You can look at it with the max metric on $\Bbb R^n\times \Bbb R^n$. That is for $p = (p_1, p_2) \in \Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R^n$ and $q = (q_1, q_2) \in \Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R^n$, define $d_\max(p, q) = \max\{d(p_1,q_1),d(p_2,q_2)\}$, where $d$ is the standard Euclidean metric on $\Bbb R^n$.

Since $A_1$ and $A_2$ are open, for each $u \in A_1$ (or $A_2$), there is an $r \gt 0$ such that $d(u, v) < r \implies v \in A_{1(2)}$.

So, let $x = (p, q) \in A_1\times A_2$. Since for each of $p, q$, there exists $r_p, r_q$, such that an open neighborhood of radius $r_{p}$ or $r_q$ respectively is a subset of $A_{1(2)}$, take $r = \min\{r_p, r_q\}$.

It then follows that for $y = (m, n) \in A_1 \times A_2$, you have $d_\max(x, y) = \max\{d(p, m), d(q, n)\} < r \implies y \in A_1\times A_2$, so $A_1\times A_2$ is open.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, for any two topological spaces, $X$ and $Y$ one has the product topology on $X\times Y$ whose basis elements are given by  $\mathscr B=\left \{ \pi^{-1}_1 (U)\cap \pi^{-1}_2(V):U\in \tau _X, V\in \tau_Y \right \}$.

I am assuming that you mean the product toplogy on $\mathbb R^{n}\times \mathbb R^{n}$. If so, the answer is yes, by definition. That is, if $A_1,A_2\in \mathbb R^{n}$ are open then $A_1\times A_2=\pi^{-1}_1(A_1)\cap \pi^{-1}_2(A_2)$ are open in $\mathbb R^{n}\times \mathbb R^{n}$.

Remark: it is not too hard to show that the metric defined in the previous answer induces the product topology on $\mathbb R^{n}\times \mathbb R^{n}$